# Node watch EPERM when the watched folder is deleted

Tags: javascript, windows, node.js, fs

I am having hard time watching folder with nodejs fs.watch on my windows machine. It raises exception when the watched folder is deleted.

```
    fs.watch('somedir', function (event, filename) {
        console.log('event is: ' + event);
        if (filename) {
            console.log('filename provided: ' + filename);
        } else {
            console.log('filename not provided');
        }
    });
```

When I delete somedir it raises an exception rather than a callback.

Comment: EPERM means operation not permitted. Check directory permissions.

Comment: Permission are all set. This only happens after the folder is deleted not before.

Comment: i don''t think you should delete a a folder you are watching, if you want to monitor the deletion of a folder, watch it's parent

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer why not? what if Grunt deletes and regenerates it's contents. why do you think just "he watches a folder, go there, right click and deletes it"?

Answer (score 0):

[fs.watch](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) returns a [fs.FSWatcher](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_fswatcher) object, that can raise an error.

I've just tested this and it seems the error event is raised when the folder is deleted.
Here is the code to handle it:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var path = "C:\\somedir";

var watcher = fs.watch(path, function (event, filename) {
  console.log('event is: ' + event);
  if (filename) {
    console.log('filename provided: ' + filename);
  } else {
    console.log('filename not provided');
  }
});


watcher.on('error', function(err) {
  if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
    console.log('folder deleted');
  }
});
```